# Nested lists in mmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mmenu

I'm using the mmenu plugin for off-canvas navigation. On mobile the main menu slides in from the left when a toggle button is clicked. On desktop I hide the toggle and the menu is displayed across the top of the browser. To keep things simple I've just hidden the menu on 'desktop' as that's not the problem - and it saves me added loads of CSS that's not needed.

The problem I'm having is on desktop I have nested lists that act like a mega menu. This all works in principle but the styling is a bit off as I have 1 `li` that acts as a heading which contains another nested list with all the options for that section.

Here's a CodePen of that working: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/NYjpPG

You can see when clicking "Fresh Meat" the panel slides along. Then if you click one of the sub-categories it slides along again, revealing more content.

If I get rid of the nested lists and use `div` tags instead it stops working. But I really would like to do this and I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work?

Here's a forked CodePen where I've replaced the nested lists with `div` elements and removed the `li` from around the 'title': https://codepen.io/moy/pen/oqWZXa

The problem is now, all the options within "Fresh Meat" now display on the same panel!

Can anyone with a bit more experience of this shed some light on why this isn't working and hopefully help me fix it?

**NOTE** The StackOverflow code snippet I've included is the version that's not working. It looks like it should work using `div's`, unless I'm reading the [mmenu help doc](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/tutorials/advanced/the-menu.html) wrong?

```js
/* ==========================================================================
   #MMENU (plugin)
   ========================================================================== */
   
/* 
 * Slide-out mobile menu with sub-menu support.
 * http://mmenu.frebsite.nl
 */
 
/* 
 * Main Menu navigation.
 */

$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".site-nav").mmenu({
  // Options
  navbar: {
   title: false
  },
  navbars: {
   "position": "top",
   "content": [
    "searchfield"
   ]
  },
  "searchfield": {
            "panel": true,
            "showSubPanels": false,
            "showTextItems": true
  }
 }, {
  // Configuration
  clone: true,
  offCanvas: {
   pageSelector: ".page"
  },
  classNames: {
   selected: "active",
   fixedElements: {
    fixed: "fixed",
    sticky: "sticky"
            }
  },
  
 });
 
 var API = $(".site-nav").data("mmenu");
 var $icon = $(".mmenu-toggle");
      
 $icon.on("click", function() {
  API.open();
 });

 API.bind( "open:finish", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
   $icon.addClass( "is-active" );
  }, 100);
 });
 
 API.bind( "close:finish", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
   $icon.removeClass( "is-active" );
  }, 100);
 });
});
```

```css
.page-head .site-nav {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/7.0.3/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/7.0.3/jquery.mmenu.all.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <header class="page-head sticky">

    <a href="#my-page" class="mmenu-toggle"><span>Menu</span></a>

    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul class="site-nav__list">
        <li class="site-nav__item has-megamenu"><span class="site-nav__link">Fresh Meat</span>

          <div class="megamenu">

            <div class="megamenu__block">
              <span class="megamenu__title">Shop by Type</span>
              <ul class="megamenu__list">
                <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="#" class="megamenu__link">Bacon and Sausages</a></li>
                <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="#" class="megamenu__link">BBQ Packs</a></li>
                <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="#" class="megamenu__link">Beef</a></li>
                <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="#" class="megamenu__link">Chicken</a></li>
                <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="#" class="megamenu__link">Christmas</a></li>
                <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="#" class="megamenu__link">Gift Packs</a></li>
                <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="#" class="megamenu__link">Lamb</a></li>
                <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="#" class="megamenu__link">Pork</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="megamenu__block">
              <span class="megamenu__title">Shop by Category</span>
              <ul class="megamenu__list">
                <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="#" class="megamenu__link">Lean Meat</a></li>
                <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="#" class="megamenu__link">Roasting Joints</a></li>
                <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="#" class="megamenu__link">Steaks</a></li>
                <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="#" class="megamenu__link">Burgers</a></li>
                <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="#" class="megamenu__link">Special Offers</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="megamenu__block">
              <span class="megamenu__title">You may also like</span>
              <div>
                <a href="#" class="megamenu__promo">
           <img src="img/temp/promo-images/megamenu-promo-1.jpg" alt="ALT TEXT" class="megamenu__promo-image" />
           <h3 class="megamenu__promo-caption">Best Buys handpicked by our head butcher</h3>
          </a>
                <a href="#" class="megamenu__promo">
           <img src="img/temp/promo-images/megamenu-promo-2.jpg" alt="ALT TEXT" class="megamenu__promo-image" />
           <h3 class="megamenu__promo-caption">Save £20 with our Monthly Meat Packs</h3>
          </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn megamenu__btn">See more deals</a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Special Offers</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Meat Boxes</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">BBQ</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Butchers Blog</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>
</div>
```